# Haskell Dependency Conflict

Tags: haskell, web, ghc, cabal

I've been trying to start writing a web app in [Scotty](https://github.com/xich/scotty), but I'm getting a dependency conflict when I try to run the server. Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Site where

import Web.Scotty
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T

-- Controllers
indexController :: ActionM ()
indexController = do
    index <- liftIO $ T.readFile "public/index.html"
    html index

routes :: ScottyM ()
routes = do
    get "/" indexController

main :: IO ()
main = do
    scotty 9901 routes
```

When I run it using `runhaskell Site.hs`, I get the following error:

```
Site.hs:12:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `text-0.11.2.3:Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
                with actual type `Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
    In the first argument of `html', namely `index'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: html index
    In the expression:
      do { index <- liftIO $ T.readFile "public/index.html";
           html index }
```

Using `cabal list text`, it tells me that versions `0.11.2.3` and `0.11.3.1` are installed, but `0.11.3.1` is the default. Scotty's `scotty.cabal` specifies that the `text` package must be `>= 0.11.2.3`, which seems to me like the above code should work. Are there any workarounds for this sort of error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message

```
Site.hs:12:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `text-0.11.2.3:Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
                with actual type `Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text'
```

means that your `scotty` was compiled using version 0.11.2.3 of the `text` package, but the invocation of runhaskell chose to use version 0.11.3.1 (because that's the newest you have, and you haven't told it to use a different version). The (lazy) `Text` types of two different package versions are, as far as GHC is concerned, two completely different types, and therefore, you must use the exact version of `text` used to compile the `scotty` library to run the code.

```
runhaskell -package=text-0.11.2.3 Site.hs
```

ought to work. If you compile the module, you also need to tell GHC to use the right version of `text`, either directly or via Cabal.

Another option could be to recompile `scotty` against the newer `text` version.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to set the default package globally?

Comment: No, not really. By default the newest (as indicated by the highest version number) version of a package is used. You can hide a version that you don't want to use, `ghc-pkg hide foo-0.1.2.3`, and then GHC won't use that version unless you explicitly tell it to. So hiding all newer versions is kind of making some version the default.